# Log4j is not working as it was in previous version of java

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I recently upgraded my application from Java 8 to Java 17 and made a few upgrades related to library for compatibility but, my log4j log level which was previously set throw code is not working. The log level is getting picked from `log4j2.xml` file.

log4j jar used is 2.16.0

FYI

> Configurator.setAllLevels(LogManager.getLogger(getRootPackage.get()).getName(), "INFO");

In my log4j2.xml

```xml
<logger name="com" level="trace" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
</logger>
```

My log level for applications is trace, whereas I want it to be info.

I tried upgrading the log4j jar tried other approaches to dynamically change the log level none is working. I'm using Jetty server.

Comment: Do you use the original `log4j-*` jars or do you repackage them into a fat-/uber-jar?

Comment: original logj-* upgraded the version as well, it didn't work too.

Comment: Log4j 2.x uses multi-release jars to support both Java 8 and Java 9+. Shading is the most common reason that breaks multi-release jars, but another possibility is that your Jetty server does not support multi-release jars. What version of Jetty are you using?

Comment: that's correct, and after enabling <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release> in my pom plugin it is working, not sure about the root cause of it but for now it solved my problem.

Comment: You're currently using an unsafe version of Log4j (or at least: it has known vulnerabilities). Upgrade to 2.17.1.

Comment: Thanks for this info will use the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding below line in my pom file plugin resolved this issue for me.

```xml
<manifestEntries>
    <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
</manifestEntries>
```